# Apache execute script when reloading

Tags: apache, web, webserver

I would like to run a script every time apache is reloaded. I could write myself a wrapper but we have already different scripts that reload it as part of their routine and I don't want to modify them. Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You could just add a PerlModule directive to your httpd.conf file - for example.

```
PerlModule Startup
```

Then in your Startup.pm module :

```
package Startup;
use strict;
use warnings;
print STDERR "Do something here!\n";
1;
```